# How can I downgrade iTunes 10.5 Beta 7 to the regular iTunes 10.5

Tags: iphone, itunes

I installed iTunes 10.5 Beta. I want to go back to the regular version of iTunes on the iTunes website. When I try and install it, I get an error saying the version on my computer is newer, so it can't. My version of iTunes will expire. I don't want to upgrade to the next beta. I just want the regular iTunes. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about pre release software are off topic for this site. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes 10.5.1 beta 3 was released yesterday, which is a good indicator that it will be formally released Real Soon Now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to delete the beta before installing the public version?

Answer (score 0):

Download version 10.5 of iTunes from Apple: http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ - and install it - maybe throw the old beta iTunes in the Trash first.

And How-to remove iTunes completely first: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=4045